# R, using Knitr to view a table in HTML

Tags: r, knitr

I feel like I am making this more difficult than it is. All I need to do is make a table from my .csv document and then Knit it to show up in an HTML document and ioslides presentation. I am working in RMarkDown in RStudio. The start of the code is just this:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results='hide',message=FALSE}    
DF <- read.csv('DF.csv', header = TRUE)
```
````

Where my data is something like this (but as a .csv):

```
     Animal  num1  num2 
0    22      36.6   213      
1    39      42.44  141      
2    40      39     157
```

And I have tried things like:

````
```{r}
DF
```
````

But that just throws all the data onto a slide without putting it into a table. When I try things such as

````
```{r table2, results='asis', message=FALSE} 
print(xtable(head(Df))) 
```
````

Or:

````
```{r table2, results='asis', message=FALSE} 
data.table(DF)
```
````

It runs fine when I just run the lines in R but as soon as I try to run Knitr it comes up with the error message "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "data.table" Calls: handle-> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval-> eval Execution halted". So I thought maybe I had to covert the table to a markdown document and then I could Knit it. Such as:

````
```{r table2, results='asis', message=FALSE} 
kable(head(DF), format = "markdown")
```
````

No such luck though, clicking Knitr just ran it to that line with an error message of: ""Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "kable" Calls: handle-> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval-> eval Execution halted". Does Knitr not recognize these functions or am I just going about this completely wrong. I want the table to look like this:

[image: table]

Comment: you have to load the data table package for data table or knitr for kable

Comment: I have both data.table and knitr packages loaded.

Comment: you have to do it in the knitr document in a code chunk

Comment: I knew I was making this harder than it is. Thank you.

Comment: @rawr Are you going to make that an answer?

Comment: @BrianDiggs I'm sure there are [similar answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752765/knitr-r-package-check-error-object-opts-chunk-not-found?answertab=votes#tab-top) somewhere, probably a duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include the libraries.  What I do is create an invisible chunk like so:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
library(pander)
```
````

I recommend PANDER which will produce a table like the one in your screenshot

````
```{r, comment=NA}
pander(DF, type = 'grid')
```
````