# R could not find function "col2rgb"

Tags: r

When I started R it came with the following Error

> Error in alpha(fill, alpha) : could not find function "col2rgb"

when I try to compile PDF in knitr I get the same error:

> Error in alpha(fill, alpha) : could not find function "col2rgb"
> Calls: .First ... grob -> gpar -> validGP -> numnotnull -> match -> alpha
> Execution halted

I don't know how to isolate this problem, since it last I used R and no when I start it produces the error. From what I can gather the col2rgb should be in the base package {grDevices}

```
library(grDevices)
grDevices::col2rgb("white")
  [,1]
red    255
green  255
blue   255
```

Which seems to work fine.
The error is independent of knitr

Anyone know a fix, or can give any suggestion as to how to isolate the problem?

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knitr: R package check error, object 'opts\_chunk' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752765/knitr-r-package-check-error-object-opts-chunk-not-found)

Comment: tried setting
    require('knitr')
    library(knitr) 
before opts_chuck.
Still nothing, and it does still report the error without running compilePDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It was due to a source("") of some often used functions that was sourced at startup via the .Rprofile. when i moved the sourcing to after Rstudio had fully started it works - even knitr.

Answer (score 2):

You must have saved your workspace.  Almost all experienced R users **never** do this.... so don't do that in the future.
For now, you'd find an `.Rdata` or `.RData` or similar in your working directory/folder and rename it (so if it contains important stuff you can still `load(.)` it manually afterward.
After that, starting R should not give your message anymore
(the `grDevices` package is one of the packages that are always loaded in R ((unless you specifically disable that; which may even be difficult in RStudio))).